# JavaScript Broken

Tags: javascript

Link:  [socalaaubaseball.com/register.html](http://socalaaubaseball.com/register.html)

Fair warning this site is super antiquated. So eyes beware.

I am helping my buddy to figure out why his JS is no longer working. My JS knowledge is super lacking so I need some major help or solution. Basically, the form on this page used to, upon 'Submission', take the person to a Thank You page and then on the backend it would email the data to my buddy. Now it is no longer doing any of that.

```
<form action="http://us.1.p9.webhosting.luminate.com/forms?login=socalaaubaseball&amp;to=eric@socalaaubaseball.com" method="post">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="597" border="0">
  <tbody>

<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="//np.lexity.com/embed/YW/6b95bf8f16e91049027d1cd1b1a534f8?id=ccda9a83ee4b"></script><script language="JavaScript" src="register_files/geov2.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">geovisit();</script>
<noscript><IMG height=1 alt=setstats src="register_files/visit.gif" width=1 
border=0></noscript> <img height="1" alt="1" src="register_files/serv.gif" width="1"> 






<script type="text/javascript">(function (d, w) {var x = d.getElementsByTagName('SCRIPT')[0];var f = function () {var s = d.createElement('SCRIPT');s.type = 'text/javascript';s.async = true;s.src = "//np.lexity.com/embed/YW/6b95bf8f16e91049027d1cd1b1a534f8?id=ccda9a83ee4b";x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);};w.attachEvent ? w.attachEvent('onload',f) :w.addEventListener('load',f,false);}(document, window));</script></form>
```

Comment: It's a regular form tag, not using any JS. How did you deduce it's a javascript problem?

Comment: please, don't add links, [edit] the question to add the simplified code. It's much better to us that are trying to find errors

Comment: Thanks Calvin sorry about that.

Comment: There's many bugs, open the console in the DevTools [F+12] and check them while navigating in the page

Comment: Thanks Calvin I will do that now.

Comment: @CalvinNunes I keep seeing this geoV2.js not found, which I am not sure if this is the main issue.

Answer (score 0):

If the code hasn't been changed and just suddenly stopped working, it is most likely configuration on the hosting company...email config, domain issues, or their form submission is broken, etc.

Comment: Thanks @john I will look into that. That is what I am assuming as well.